# How to get getters from object?

Tags: php

My SimpleClass:

```
class Simple
{
    private $test;

    public function other() {};
    public function getTest() {};
    public function setTest() {};
    public function getSecond() {};
    public function setSecond() {};
}
```

How to get from this class all getters?

```
$ref = new \ReflectionClass(new SimpleClass());
$allMethods = $ref->getMethods();
```

And how can I get from $allMethods only getters (getTest, getSecond)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php), the getMethods method returns an array so simply looping across it should yield what you want.

The returned array is an array of [reflectionMethod objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) so you could even look at the visibility properties - i.e. `->isPublic()`

```
<?PHP

class Simple
{
    private $test;

    public function other() {}
    public function getTest() {}
    public function setTest() {}
    public function getSecond() {}
    public function setSecond() {}
}

$ref = new \ReflectionClass(new SimpleClass());
$allMethods = $ref->getMethods();

$getters = array();
$publicGetters = array();

for ($methodNum=0; $methodNum < count($allMethods); $methodNum++)
{
        if( substr( $allMethods[$methodNum]->getName(), 0, 3 ) == 'get' )
        {
            $getters[] = $allMethods[$methodNum];
            if( $allMethods[$methodNum]->isPublic() )
            {
                $publicGetters[] = $allMethods[$methodNum];
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after each of your class functions, there shouldn't be a `;`, otherwise it will throw a Syntax

> syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Now, to get the getters and setters, you can loop through the methods and compare their names:

```
$getters = array();
$setters = array();
$methods = $ref->getMethods();

foreach($methods as $method){

    $name = $method->getName();

    if(strpos($name, 'get') === 0)
        array_push($getters, $method);
    else if(strpos($name, 'set') === 0)
        array_push($setters, $method);

}
```

And the result of `$getters` will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionMethod)#3 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "getTest"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "Simple"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(ReflectionMethod)#5 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "getSecond"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "Simple"
  }
}
```

And the result of `$setters` will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionMethod)#4 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "setTest"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "Simple"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(ReflectionMethod)#6 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "setSecond"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "Simple"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array looking for methods starting with `get`, optionally checking if they are `public`:

```
$getMethods = array_filter($allMethods, function($o) {
                                          return stripos($o->name, 'get') === 0
                                                 && $o->isPublic();
                                        });
```

If you only want the `name` and aren't concerned with `public` (PHP 7):

```
$getMethods = preg_grep('/^get/i', array_column($allMethods, 'name'));
```

A bit easier if you don't use reflection:

```
$allMethods = get_class_methods('SimpleClass');
$getMethods = preg_grep('/^get/i', $allMethods);
```